# How to Remove (alphabet & Special )characters from a String and store to one array?

Tags: java, regex, arrays, sorting

my String Data is like `DV_APLCN: 563 ,DV_DHR_APLCN: 5632, PIC_NOTE: 6254`...etc.

So I need to separate only digit( i.e ,563,3632,6254)s and need to store in an array.

Help me on this.with sample code. data is very huge and different StringNames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You need to understand [Java regular expression `Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and then consider using [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) .

```
String str = "DV_APLCN: 563 ,DV_DHR_APLCN: 5632, PIC_NOTE: 6254";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.split("\\D+")));
```

Output

```
[, 563, 5632, 6254]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using regex [Regex Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html).

And no one will provide you with java code. You need to show some effort from your side.